# On the Lebesgue measure

Tags: measure-theory

Here is an exercise that I am trying to make :

Assume that $f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is a Borel function. Show that for $\lambda$ (Lebesgue measure) almost all $y \in \mathbb{R}$, $\lambda(\{x \in \mathbb{R}: f(x)=y\})=0$

However, I am not sure to understand it. Indeed, for example, if $\{x \in \mathbb{R}: f(x)=y\}=[0,1]$, then the Lebesgue measure should be $1$. Are you seeing my mistake ?

Thank you,

Comment: “for almost all $y\in\Bbb{R}$”, so what you wrote isn’t a counterexample.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I am unfortunatly not sure to understand what "for almost all $y \in \mathbb{R}$" means here. May I ask you to explain it to me ?

Comment: I could, but I won’t because this is explained in every textbook, so what does your textbook/notes say? (you could even google it)

Comment: Hint: consider two points $y_1$ and $y_2$ and the corresponding sets ${x:f(x)=y_1} and {x:f(x)=y_2}$: have they some common point? The exercise asks to prove that the set of all those  $y$ such that the measure of $f^{-1}(y)$ is positive, that set has measure zero.